# Vertical height of the background-image

Tags: html, css, position, background-image

I have situation. I'm using header full-width image, so width is 100% and height I have fixed to 650px.
I need to position image in the way, that in case I will increase or decrease browser width, background image will only increase or decrease width, and not move image vertically.

I hope I've wroted it understandable. If not enought, here is a screenshot

Current situation

[image]

My desired situation

[image]

SCSS code

```
header {
    margin-top: 78px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    max-width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.header-main {
    background-image:url(../img/header.jpg);
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
```

HTML

```
<header class="header-main" >
        ---Content---
</header>
```

Thank you soo much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the background-size

```
header {
    margin-top: 78px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: auto 650px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: calc(100% - 120px);
}

.header-main {
    background-image:url(../img/header.jpg);
    height: 650px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip but unfortunatelly it's not working as it's not stretch the image to full-width

Comment: Change the 'auto' into the full-width with pixels in the background-size: auto 650px?